# Serialize KeyValuePair as [Key,Value] in JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, keyvaluepair

I need to return json with this structure :

```
{"asks": [[PRICE, AMOUNT], ...],
 "bids": [[PRICE, AMOUNT], ...]}
```

`PRICE` is decimal. `AMOUNT` is decimal

example

```
{"asks":[[7.449,1],[7.4499,6.711]],
 "bids":[[7.40001,5],[7.3325,27.449]]}
```

I have a controller with action

```
public ActionResult GetTrades() 
{
  ///how should I construct the object ? 
  return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I've tried to return this object :

```
public class OrderBook
{
    public List<KeyValuePair<decimal, decimal>> asks { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<decimal, decimal>> bids { get; set; }
}
```

but I get response like this:

```
{"asks":[{"Key":145.00000,"Value":152.38820689}],
 "bids":[{"Key":145.00000,"Value":3.48965517}]}
```

any Idea?

Comment: `List<List<decimal>> asks` should work, or *perhaps* a [Tuple(T1,T2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx)? Don't use KeyValuePair here. However, if it makes more sense to use KeyValuePair (or a different data-type, like `Trade`) internally, just map it to something "easily serializable" right before transmission.

Comment: 10x ,how do I sign your answer as correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `KeyValuePair` with either a `List<decimal>` or `decimal[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using the same data type for key and value then perhaps List is a possibility, where each decimal array would be of length 2 in your case.